# How to do name binding in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a long expression like `self.table[25].hello[23]`. I want to set `self.table[25].hello[23] = Foo()`, but I don't want to type out `self.table[25].hello[23]`. I want to  do something like:

```
temp = self.table[25].hello[23]
temp = Foo()
```

Obviously this doesn't work in Python since it only makes temp now point to Foo(). Is there someway to do a stronger name binding in Python?

Comment: In the middle part of this document: (http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html) there are sections: _Other languages have "variables"_. _Python has "names"_. It's a nice explanation with pictures why it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

No, not really.

Untested:

```
class itemsetter:
  def __init__(self, obj, el):
    self.obj = obj
    self.el = el

  def __call__(self, val):
    self.obj[self.el] = val

setindex = itemsetter(self.table[25].hello, 23)
setindex(Foo())
```